# try catch inside while loop in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to prevent users from entering a non-numeric and negative value.
while variable digit is <= 0, the loop will continue. if try catch an error then the digit will be set to 0 to enter the loop again. but instead of turning back to ask the user to input a number when the user inputs a non-numeric value, it enters an infinite loop.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int digit = 0;
        String playerNUmber;

        while (digit <= 0) {

            System.out.println("How many digit you want to guess?");
            try {

                digit = s.nextInt();

                char[][] users = new char[digit][1];

                do {
                    System.out.println("Please enter " + digit + " digit/s numbers.");
                    playerNUmber = s.next();

                    if (playerNUmber.length() == digit) {
                        System.out.println("Player number : " + playerNUmber);

                        for (int i = 0; i < digit; i++) {
                            users[i][0] = playerNUmber.charAt(i);

                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You must enter a " + digit + " number.");
                    }

                } while (playerNUmber.length() != digit);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Enter numbers only");
                digit = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use *break* and *labeled break* statements? This would make things a lot easier.

Comment: you need to clear the buffer by calling `sc.nextLine()` after `sc.nextInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Scanner, when an InputMismatchException is thrown, Scanner is not going to the next token because it gives us the opportunity to handle that token.

In your case, you need to invalidate the token. To do that you can simply use nextLine inside the catch block:

```
s.nextLine();
```